# Can i set new config.properties file in jar file?

Tags: java, maven, jar

Did "mvn package"

```
mvn package
```

After this i need to change config.properties in .jar file via command line

How can i do that?

Comment: What exactly are you changing in `config.properties` that you have to do it after `package` phase?

Comment: Change that property file before you package your jar file ...otherwise it does not really make sense...

Comment: cuz if i need only jar file and some properties will be changed(db.pass or port, for example) i can change it fast and not necessary to have initial project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Command line:

```
jar uf yourfile.jar dir{optional}/config.properties
```